# Method or Data Member not found Error

Tags: vba, outlook, combobox

I am trying to filter my combobox on Outlook Macro. But I am getting the error as mentioned on title. Could you please help me to solve this problem?
It works on Visual Studio but doesn't work on Outlook Macro.

```
Private Sub cmbProjects_Change()
    Dim SelectedText As String
    SelectedText = cmbProjects.text

    Dim Items As Object
    Items = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Items = cmbProjects.Items

    Dim newList As Object
    newList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each Item In Items
        If Item.Contains(SelectedText) Then
            newList.Add (Item)
        End If
    Next

    cmbProjects.DataSource = newList
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you update the code pointing to the line where you get the error?

Comment: **Items = cmbProjects.Items** I am getting just right here

Comment: You need to add the **Set** keyword at the beginning.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev perhaps you missed out the answer that contains the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `set` since it's an object reference. And you are trying to access this object's (you assumed as an ArrayList) with its member methods/properties. Which fails. So change to,

```
Set Items = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Set newList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

Further check if you have the right reference added in your VBA editor for collection library objects.

```
CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

As per my comments, `Items = cmbProjects.Items` also fails with the same error. [That's because `cmbProjects` doesn't have a method called Items. So you need to use `List` instead.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868268.aspx). List returns a variant object.

Since you can't cast a variant into an ArrayList. You have to iterate through the variant and add items into the ArrayList. Note I am writing on the fly, the code is not tested. You may test it out and comment, should you need further assistance. *I strongly recommend you to validate this pseudo-code against the accurate syntax.*

```
Dim vr as Variant
Dim i as Integer

vr = cmbProject.List

'--add error handling to check if vr is empty or if cmbProject is empty.
For i = 0 to UpperBound(vr)

   Items.Add (vr(i))
Next i
```

Comment: It is just a combobox. I need to get its items and filter when text change :/

Comment: [You can try `cmbProject.List`, this doesn't show an `Items` as a property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868268.aspx) That could well be the reason for getting a memeber/method not found error.

Comment: Now It says Variable not defined :/

Comment: I dont know how to use it is there any article to read ? Thank you so much bonCodigo

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8rD_I1WntkmWS1FczhISEFTVFE/view?usp=sharing) Can you check the here?

Comment: Please refer to my answer's update. Can you add those variables and set up the `for loop`?